# How to find string with regex.compile and ignore everything what goes after that string

Tags: python, regex

I am practicing regex and right now I have made this sample :

```
import re
test_obj_A = 'some_testObj_Asomething'
pattern = re.compile(r'_A')
subbed = pattern.sub(r'_B', test_obj_A)
print(subbed)
```

My question is how to ignore in compile everything what goes after *'_A'* and get result in **subbed** - 'test_obj_B'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just replace everything after `_A.*` with `_B`

```
>>> import re
>>> x
'some_testObj_Asomething'
>>> re.sub(r'_A.*', '_B', x)
'some_testObj_B'
```